# Differential equation of the form $(y')^2=\alpha y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $y=ax^2+bx+c$ is tested in the differential equation $(y')^2=\alpha y$, a general solution can be found with a free constant.

But are all solutions of $(y')^2=\alpha y$ in this form?

Comment: What if the right side is negative? Did you try the equation after the square root on both sides? See: examples for the Peano theorem.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those infamous non-Lipschitz cases for which you can't use [Picard–Lindelöf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem). Note that the function
$$ y(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x<a \\ \frac{1}{4}\alpha(x-a)^2 & x \geqslant a \end{cases} $$
also satisfies the differential equation for any $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Real solutions of $y'^2=\alpha\, y$ exist when $\alpha $ and $ y$ are of same sign. The parabola cannot cut the x-axis, should be either above or below it. To  conform to the differential equation $\alpha >0 $ above x-axis and  $\alpha <0 $ below.

Differentiate and and cancel $ y^{'},$ and integrate twice.

$$ y^{''} = \alpha/2 $$

$$ y = \frac{\alpha x^2}{4} + b x + c  $$

have  extreme value  $ c - \dfrac{b^2}{\alpha}$

[image: parabola]